# How to add CSS style to HTML elements created with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created HTML elements with JavaScript to pull data from the back-end server. I am trying to add CSS style to the elements, but I am having trouble as to how.

I have tried using getElementById and setAttribute, but I'm keep getting an error. Whenever each item is pulled out from the back-end server, I want each information to be wrapped with a solid black border.

This is the code:

```
let div = "<div>";
        
        for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {

            div += "<h3>" + Items[i].title + "</h3><p><i><b> Posted: " + Items[i].time + "</b></i></p><p>" + Items[i].body + "</p>"

        }

        div += "</div>";

        $("#news-articles").html(div);
```

Comment: create a css class and add that class while creating your dynamic HTML

Comment: Can I get more information? Any examples I can refer to please?

Comment: You can also add a class name or id for the HTML element created using js and add styles in the CSS file for those classes or id. Or if you want to add them from javascript then also it is easy to get the element via id or class and add styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class` or `style` attributes while creating the HTML string like:

```
"<div class=\"red\" style=\"background: blue\">".
```

I recommend using single quotes or template literal so you wouldn't have to escape the nested double quotes:

```
'<div class="red" style="background: blue">'
```

---

```js
const Items = [{
  title: 'hi',
  time: 2,
  body: 'hello'
}]

let div = "<div class=\"red\" style=\"background: blue\">";

for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {

  div += "<h3>" + Items[i].title + "</h3><p><i><b> Posted: " + Items[i].time + "</b></i></p><p>" + Items[i].body + "</p>"

}

div += "</div>";

$("#news-articles").html(div);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="news-articles"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You complicate the code a lot. Just use list tags

```
    <ul>
    for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
   <li>Coffee</li>....}
```

```
   ul li {
  background: #cce5ff;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your CSS?

Just load a CSS file with styles for every element inside the #news-articles container:

```
#news-articles h3 {
/* rules */
}

#news-articles p {
/* rules */
}

etc...
```

I suggest you to wrap  every news in a div for easily achieving what you pretend, which is adding a border to each of them.

```
for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {

            div += "<div class='container'><h3>" + Items[i].title + "</h3><p><i><b> Posted: " + Items[i].time + "</b></i></p><p>" + Items[i].body + "</p></div>"

        }
```

And then...

```
#news-articles .container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: HTML attributes are supposed to be wrapped in double quotes, even though browser will handle it, writing `class='container'` in JS is very unnatural imo.

Comment: What you must care about is "consistency". There's no problem with using single quotes if whole HTML code uses it. Same goes for Javascript.